# Load data from SharedPreferences and populate listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I've been working for quite some time for this but still couldn't get it right. I'm trying to create a simple app that allows user to add items into a list manually and the items are stored permanently using SharedPreferences. But I keep couldn't get it right (I'm really a noob in programming btw). Can anyone give any suggestions? Thank you very much!

```
public class Mainmemo extends Activity {
public ArrayList<User> arrayOfUsers = User.getUsers();
public ListView listView;
public CustomUsersAdapter adapter;
public SharedPreferences sharedpref;
public Bundle extra;
public static final String PREFERENCES_TODO = "TODO_List_Shared_Preferences";



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_list);
    populateUsersList();
}


private void populateUsersList() {


    adapter = new CustomUsersAdapter(this, arrayOfUsers);


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvUsers);
    final TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty);
    final Button manualaddmemo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addmemo);
    listView.setEmptyView(textview);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    listView.setClickable(true);


    extra = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extra != null) {
        String text = extra.getString("text");
        String date = extra.getString("dateoftext");
        extra = null;
        savestringtopreferences(text, date);

    }



    manualaddmemo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent newIntent = new Intent(Mainmemo.this, add_memo_to_list.class);
            startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
        }
    });
}

private void savestringtopreferences(String text, String date) {


    sharedpref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpref.edit();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    try {
        obj.put("Name", text);
        obj.put("Category", date);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    editor.putString("JSON", obj.toString());
    editor.apply();
}
}
```

So here, I'm trying to create a listview with custom array adapter, and upon pressing Button ManualAddDemo it will navigate to another page where the user is allow to type anything they want, and whatever they typed will be parse back to the main activity (alongside with the date as another string). After doing so I tried to put both strings into a JSONObject and then save it inside shared preferences. I then retrieve the data inside my customarrayadapter so that everytime the listview is loaded, the data will be retrieved.

```
public class CustomUsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
public CustomUsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
    super(context, 0, users);
}




@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    User user = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.memolist, parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView tvdate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    TextView indexview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.indexnumber);

    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    int sequence = position +1;
    user.index = String.valueOf(sequence);

    SharedPreferences sharedpref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    String name = sharedpref.getString("JSON", "");


        try {

                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(name);


               user.name = object.getString("Name");
                user.date= object.getString("Category");
                indexview.setText(user.index);
                tvName.setText(user.name);
                tvdate.setText(user.date);




        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }



    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
```

}

my user class:

```
public class User {
public String name;
public String date;
public String index;

public User( String index, String name, String date) {
    this.index = index;
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;

}

public static ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();





    return users;
}
```

}

Any suggestions? Tqvm!

Comment: please mention what is the issue you face? Are you not being able to retrieve the item stored or what exactly is the issue?

Comment: I can save the data i wanted to, but i couldn't retrieve it in my customarrayadapter...thus whenever my listview run the items that i added won't be retrieved

Comment: Please check with debug set at the JSON object and check if it actually gets the value you need. You can check this at both the places - where you write and where you try to read.

Comment: I checked, it seems that I can properly save the JSON object and gets the value that I needed at my Main Activity, but I have trouble loading it in my custom array adapter

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment:

First, in your custom adapter class declare constructor like,

```
    public customAdapter(Context context, List<String> info){

// do whatever you want to do

}
```

And call constructor in MainActivity as:

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, infoList);
```

Comment: I tried, but I'm still facing the same problem. My customarrayadapter doesn't seem to be able to retrieve the data i saved in my sharedpreference, meaning nothing happened everytime my listview loaded

Comment: Have you checked whether data is inserted in preferences or not??

Comment: I checked, it seems that I can save the data into the preferences without a problem. I checked by trying to retrieve the data at my main activity, and it worked perfectly fine. But now my problem is I couldn't retrieve it at my Custom Array Adapter. Nothing is happening when I try to retrieve preference data at my custom array adapter...

Comment: Retrieve your data in MainActivity and pass a list to custom adapter....pass list as an argument in custom adapter's constructor and use that list to display items....

Comment: Can you send me a sample code of how to do so? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe you're overwriting objects in shared preferences. You can probably store a JSON array. When you add to it, you should first retrieve the last 
   written array and append the newest object.
2. You should use sqllite to store data, shared preferences are not for such uses.